# How do you copy a file to a folder with {name:"XXX-X-XXXX" & foo} in Applescript

Tags: applescript, duplicates, directory

I have a script I need to write where I have created a folder with this script (below) but cant figure out how to copy a file to the created folder because how its named.

```
set foo to computer name of (system info)
tell application "Finder"
    set home_path to home as Unicode text
    set targetFile to (home_path & "Library:Logs:Xxxxx.log")
    set p to (path to desktop)
    try
    set targetPath to make new folder at p with properties **{name:"XXX-X-XXXX" & foo}**
        duplicate file targetFile to targetPath
    end try
end tell
```

I thought I could write a script like this.

```
set foo to computer name of (system info)


    tell application "Finder"
        set p to (path to desktop)

        set home_path to home as Unicode text
        set targetFile to (home_path & "Library:Logs:Xxxxx.log")
        set p to (path to desktop)
        try
            set targetPath to p & {name:"LOGS-I-NEED" & foo}
            duplicate file targetFile to targetPath
        end try
        try
        on error the error_message number the error_number
            display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        end try

    end tell
```

But I get this error

--> error number -1700 from {alias "Macintosh HD:Users:dorianglanville:Desktop:", "LOGS-I-NEEDDorian's MacBook"} to folder

I feel like I'm missing something simple but have been staring at it so long I can no longer "see" it.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Did you want to put an extra colon between `LOGS-I-NEED` and `Dorian's MacBook`?

Comment: Yes actually that would be great.

Comment: Does that solve it then?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you meant by that, no sorry the name should be LOGS-I-NEEDDorian's MacBook .

Comment: I can't tell you it is wrong but I don't like an apostrophe in a file/folder name. Error -1700 seems to be related to troublesome characters. Could that be it? What is the file name you are trying to copy?

Comment: Viive.log , so no special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there were a few things you needed to straighten out, the error has nothing to do with the apostrophe.

```
error number -1700 from {alias "Macintosh HD:Users:dorianglanville:Desktop:", "LOGS-I-NEEDDorian's MacBook"} to folder
```

Notice that the targetPath is composed of two items. You need to coerce it to text.

```
set foo to computer name of (system info)
set p to (path to desktop)
set targetFile to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Logs:Xxxxx.log"
set targetPath to p & "LOGS-I-NEED" & foo as text

try
    tell application "Finder" to duplicate file targetFile to targetPath
on error the error_message number the error_number
    display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message & return & "targetFile:" & targetFile & return & return & "targetPath:" & targetPath buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end try
```